# A transparent JFrame that is always on top, but allows clicking underneath

Tags: java, file, jframe, transparent

So, i'm making a program that currently just accepts a file that'd been dragged and dropped into it. I'm using a JFrame for the container at the moment, but I dont think that's really important.

I want the window to always be on top when running, so that if you drag any file to the bottom right corner of the screen, the program will handle it. But, at the same time, i want the program to be able to be invisible, and click-through-able, meaning that you can click on anything underneath the jframe, while it's invisible, but still be able to drag a file into the program without having to do anything special.

I've never heard of something like this, but I'm sure it must be possible. How would I do this?

Comment: What makes you say it is possible. If I open a full screen application and give it focus, I will never be able to drag-and-drop something onto that `JFrame`, transparent or not.

Comment: well right now, it is always on top. so as long as no one minimizes it, it will always be on top. This doesn't have to be the case with full screen games, but I want it open any time there could be a file drag. The trick really for me is, making behind it clickable. Could i just use a mouse listener, and have java click behind the program for the user? instead of the user being the one to click, java's doing it?

Comment: Let's say you can make a full screen transparent `JFrame` and allow clicks to go through it, meaning you are clicking on the application underneath it. That will give focus to that application, and bring it to the front and your `JFrame` to the back

Comment: with `JFrame.alwaysOnTop(true);`, even if you give focus to another program, the JFrame is still on top, and I'm still able to drag a file into it. All I need is to be able to interact with what's underneath. The Frame is also not full screen, simply a 250x150 square at the bottom right of the screen

Comment: @PulsePanda do you want a frame that's always on top.and you should able to drag files to it and if you click on the frame it should click underneath ??

Comment: @getlost yes, that is exactly what I want. Be able to drag a file to the JFrame and have it handle (currently works with just being `alwaysOnTop`), but be able to click on the area beneath the frame as well

Comment: Have you tried the answer to this question?
[Clicking Past a Transparent Frame (Java)][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524132/clicking-past-a-transparent-frame-java?rq=1

Comment: I have, the problem is that the window wont be transparent, only translucent. I was thinking on having a mouse listener, and just clicking on the screen beneath it using the coordinates, but i've tried various methods of doing this, and none have really worked (the issue is actually getting it to click underneath, setting the location is easy)

Comment: *I've never heard of something like this, but I'm sure it must be possible.* I admire your optimism. I think you might be able to do it with native code. (**Note**: I said *admire*, *think* and *might*. Not I have done this and here is how I did it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a Splash screen the other day that was click-through-able. You might want to make a completely transparent image using Photoshop or something else. Here is the code:

```
private BufferedImage splash;

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public Splash() {
    this.setUndecorated(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    setSize(500, 500);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    try {
        splash = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/images/transparent.png"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Apply a transparent color to the background
    // This is REALLY important, without this, it won't work!
    setBackground(new Color(0, 255, 0, 0));
    getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(splash)));
    setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Looks like Splash class should extend JFrame.

Comment: I'll definitely try this out when I get home, updates to come :)

Comment: This works perfectly :) Thank you so very much! Here's some rep points :)